# How to know which tuples do not meet a certain condition?

Tags: sql

My database consists of 3 tables with the following attributes:

Table 1: car_id, place

Table 2: driver_id, car_brand, car_type

Table 3: system_id, car_id, driver_id, weight, length

The question is about the car_brand: Toyota and I have to only look at the car_type: sedan, jeep and hatchback

I want to know which tuples in table 3 do not meet the following conditions:

weight-100+5*length< 1000 (if this is a sedan or hatchback)

weight-100+5*length> 1000 (if this is jeep)

I have tried to do the following code:

```
SELECT car_brand, car_type, table2.diver_id
               FROM table3, table2
               WHERE car_brand = 'Toyota'
               AND ((weight-100)+(5*length) < 1000) AND car_type = 'sedan' OR 'hatchback'
               AND ((weight-100)+(5*length) > 1000) AND car_type = 'jeep'")
```

I don't know if this is correct or not

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`!!!

```
SELECT t2.car_brand, t2.car_type, t2.diver_id
FROM table3 t3 JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t3.driver_id = t2.driver_id
WHERE t2car_brand = 'Toyota' AND
      ( ((t3.weight-100)+(5*t3.length) < 1000) AND t2.car_type IN ('sedan', 'hatchback')) OR
        ((t3.weight-100)+(5*t3.length) > 1000) AND t2.car_type = 'jeep')
      );
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- Qualify all column references.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- In the first condition, you want `IN`.  Your construct doesn't make sense.

EDIT:

If you want rows where these conditions are not met:

```
SELECT t2.car_brand, t2.car_type, t2.diver_id
FROM table3 t3 JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t3.driver_id = t2.driver_id
WHERE t2car_brand = 'Toyota' AND
      NOT ( ((t3.weight-100)+(5*t3.length) < 1000) AND t2.car_type IN ('sedan', 'hatchback')) OR
            ((t3.weight-100)+(5*t3.length) > 1000) AND t2.car_type = 'jeep')
          );
```

Comment: Thankyou very much! This code will show me the tuples that meet the 2 conditions, but how can I get the tuples that don't meet the 2 conditions?